# AWS Workspaces disconnecting after recieving new code and reinstalling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I am using AWS Workspaces with the Workspaces client on mac and I get the error message:

> Disconnected.
> You have been disconnected, either because you also logged in from another location, your host was shut down or restarted, or a network error occccured. Try to log in again. If you're unable to log in, contact your WorkSpaces administrator for help.

I have checked a few things already:

- Checked network connection through amazon(using mac, clicked on connections in top bar) everything checked out
- Checked internet connection of router
- Checked to make sure I am the only user for this workspace(I am also the admin)
- Deleted workspace and started a new one to generate a new registration code
- Removed and re downloaded WorkSpaces client
- Deleted all resources related to this workspace including directory and WorkDocs and started over from scratch

But nothing seems to be working, any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been found that at this time clients can only connect Ubuntu workspaces via `Windows Workspaces Client` or `Web Access`. So, if you are using any other local OS client like Linux or Mac OS etc. it is expected that you will the above error message. The reason for the delayed clients, is that the new Ubuntu WorkSpaces are based on the WSP Protocol, not the existing PCOIP streaming protocol, and only the Windows client supports WSP at the time of the Launch. Our internal team is working on making Ubuntu WorkSpaces available for other clients as well.